# Spring data jdbc error BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar, while trying to save simple Aggregate

Tags: spring-boot, solr, java-11, spring-data-jdbc

I've below domain model objects, with below DDL and spring version, when i try to save the complete aggregate (just two entities) spring-data below error.

So I'm thinking that either i don't have my aggregates or my DDL defined correctly or hitting a blocker in spring-data-jdbc.

I've created sample git repo here:
https://github.com/rajeshhazari/spring-boot-samples

Any help, suggestion on this will be much appreciated.

My Entities, Repo and Junit testcase and stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.Delete(rootId=1, propertyPath=appUsersAuthList)

    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DefaultAggregateChange.forEachAction(DefaultAggregateChange.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:339)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.test.springjdbcsample1.springjdbcsampletest1Tests.repositoryTest(springjdbcsampletest1Tests.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM "appusers_auth" WHERE "appusers_auth"."userid" = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "appusers_auth" not found; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM "appusers_auth" WHERE "appusers_auth"."userid" = ? [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:883)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:321)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.delete(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:222)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeDelete(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:74)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "appusers_auth" not found; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM "appusers_auth" WHERE "appusers_auth"."userid" = ? [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSimpleTableFilter(Parser.java:1350)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseDelete(Parser.java:1377)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:914)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:237)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615)
    ... 98 more
```

```
@Table("APPUSERS")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUsers implements Serializable {
    private @Id
    Long userid;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    @MappedCollection(idColumn="userid", keyColumn="userid")
    private Set<AppUsersAuth> appUsersAuthList ;
}
```

```
public interface AppUserRepository extends CrudRepository<AppUsers, Long> {

    @Query("select * from APPUSERS where upper(email) = upper(:email)   ")
    AppUsers findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

```
@Table("appusers_auth")
@Data
public  class AppUsersAuth {
    @Column("auth_user_id")
    private Long authUserId;
    @Column("userid")
    private Long userid;
    private String email;
    @Column("role_id")
    private String roleId;
    @Column("username")
    private String username;


}
```

```
CREATE TABLE APPUSERS(
  userid identity not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY ,
  username VARCHAR(100) not null unique ,
  password VARCHAR(100) not null,
  email VARCHAR(100) not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE appusers_auth (
 auth_user_id identity not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY  ,
 userid BIGINT NOT NULL ,
 username text,
 email text NOT NULL,
 role_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 updated_time timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringjdbcsampletestApp.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public class springjdbcsampletest1Tests {

    @Autowired
    AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Test
    void repositoryTest() {
        //appUserRepository.deleteAll();
        AuthoritiesMaster authoritiesMaster = new AuthoritiesMaster();
        authoritiesMaster.setRoleId("role_basic");
        authoritiesMaster.setRoledesc("Basic Role Desc");

        //appUsersAuth.setRoleId(authoritiesMaster.getRoleId());
        AppUsersAuth appUsersAuth = new AppUsersAuth();
        appUsersAuth.setEmail("test1@mail.com");
        appUsersAuth.setRoleId("role_basic");

        AppUsers appUsers = new AppUsers();
        appUsers.setUsername("test1");
        appUsers.setEmail("test1@mail.com");
        appUsers.setPassword("test123");


        appUsersAuth.setUsername(appUsers.getUsername());
        appUsersAuth.setUserid(appUsers.getUserid());
        appUsers = appUserRepository.save(appUsers);
        appUsersAuth.setUserid(appUsers.getUserid());
        appUsers = appUserRepository.save(appUsers);
        Assertions.assertThat(appUsers).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(appUsers.getAppUsersAuthList()).isNotNull();
        Set<AppUsersAuth> appUsersAuthList = appUsers.getAppUsersAuthList();
        for (final AppUsersAuth usersAuth : appUsersAuthList) {

            /*Assertions.assertThat(usersAuth.getAppAuthoritiesMasterList()).isNotNull();
            List<AuthoritiesMaster> authoritiesMasterList = usersAuth.getAppAuthoritiesMasterList();
            authoritiesMasterList.forEach(appUsersAuthMaster -> {
                Assertions.assertThat(appUsersAuthMaster).isNotNull();
                Assertions.assertThat(appUsersAuthMaster.getRoleId()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("role_basic");
            });*/
        }
        Assertions.assertThat(appUsers.getEmail()).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the stack trace gives the important hint:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "appusers_auth" not found; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM "appusers_auth" WHERE "appusers_auth"."userid" = ? [42102-200]
```

You have the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE appusers_auth (
...
```

But that actually creates a table with all upper case name.
While Spring Data JDBC uses quoted identifiers and looks for `appusers_auth` in all lower case names.

To fix the problem either use

```
CREATE TABLE "appusers_auth" (
...
```

I.e. quoting the table name in the create script.
Or (probably preferable) use all upper case in the `@Table` annotation.

Comment: Thanks, @Jens Schauder, I'll try the changes you have suggested over weekend and update here.

Comment: Update:
Thanks once again Jens Schauder, I've changed the code as you have suggested and all the tests have passed, for this aggregate model with two entities.
I've another question on aggregates, aggregate model with three entitties:
for the case where I've third entity with AuthoritiesMaster table, where we can define role level authorities, do you think this master table should be part of this aggregate.

Comment: Update:
Thanks once again Jens Schauder, I've changed the code as you have suggested and all the tests have passed, for this aggregate model with two entities.
Github link: [https://github.com/rajeshhazari/spring-boot-samples]

I've another question on Aggregates, aggregate model with three entities:
for the case where I've third entity with Authorities Master table, where we can define role level authorities, do you think this master table should be part of this aggregate.
`  Appusers -> AppusersAuth -> AuthoritiesMaster {  private String roleId; private String roleDesc; }`.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comments. Make it a proper question instead, so others have a chance to find it and profit from it and its answers.